# Android - Creating an Interface between a library and an application

Tags: java, android, interface, shared-libraries

I need to create an interface between a library I've built and the rest of the app - how can this be accomplished?

I've attempted to connect the two by importing them into each other as well as adding the library to the main project under the project's properties - but I still cannot seem to get the (XML) data from the library over to the primary application class.

Library:

package com.project.test.networktasklibrary;

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import com.project.test.networktasklibrary.XmlParserHandlerFinal;
import com.project.test.*;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

/*this class performs the call to webservice in the background*/
public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, InputStream> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "STDataSettings";
    private static final String TAG_RESULT = "success";
    private static InputStream stream;

    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            stream = getQueryResults("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31771876/GetPhoneSettings-ST-rsp-eng.xml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stream;
    }

    /*
     * Sends a query to server and gets back the parsed results in a bundle
     * urlQueryString - URL for calling the webservice
     */
    protected static synchronized InputStream getQueryResults(
            String urlQueryString) throws IOException, SAXException,
            SSLException, SocketTimeoutException, Exception {
        Bundle queryResults = new Bundle();

        HttpsURLConnection https = null;
        String uri = urlQueryString;
        URL urlo = new URL(uri);

        https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlo.openConnection();
        https.setConnectTimeout(50000); // 20 second timeout
        https.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        try {
            https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlo.openConnection();

            if ("gzip".equals(https.getContentEncoding())) {
                stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
            } else
                stream = https.getInputStream();

        } catch (SSLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

        }

        String queryResult = null;
        queryResults.putString(TAG_RESULT, queryResult);

        return stream;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return stream;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream queryResults) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(queryResults);
        //success();
    }
}
```

Primary Application Class:

```
package com.project.test.datasettings;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.project.test.networktasklibrary.*;
import com.project.test.networktasklibrary.NetworkTask;

public class UpdateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ImageView mProgressImageview1;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview2;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview3;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview4;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview5;
    public static int count;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    int version;
    public static int TotalSteps = 8;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "STDataSettings";
    private Button mUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private TextView mReadAgainButton = null;
    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    AlertDialog mConfirmAlert = null;
    public static InputStream stream = null;
    public static XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;
    private NetworkTask task;
    private AnimationDrawable loadingAnimation;
    private static final String TAG = "UpdateActivity";
    Context ctx;
    private Button assist_update_btn = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int networkType = tm.getNetworkType();
        int phoneType = tm.getPhoneType();
        handler = new XmlParserHandlerFinal();
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA
                || (phoneType != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE)) {
            // If the phone type is CDMA or
            // the phone phone type is not GSM and the network type is none of
            // the network types indicated in the statement
            // Display incompatibility message
            showAlert(getString(R.string.incomp_sm_dialog));
            // Network type is looked because some tablets have no phone type.
            // We rely on network type in such cases
        } else if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                || !(tm.getSimOperator()
                        .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo)) || (tm
                        .getSimOperator()
                        .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))))) {

            // if SIM is present and is NOT a T-Mo network SIM,
            // display Error message alert indicating to use SM SIM
            showAlert(getString(R.string.insert_sm_dialog));
        }// No SIM or SIM with T-Mo MNC MCC present
        else if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            // Initial UI setup for versions lower than ICS
            setContentView(R.layout.update);
            mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);

            mUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        } else {// ICS and up

            if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                            .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
                task = new NetworkTask();
                task.execute("");
                // Device has T-Mo network SIM card MCC and MNC correctly
                // populated
                // Reduce number of steps to 6
                TotalSteps = 6;
            }

        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mUpdateButton) {
            // Update button for versions lower than ICS is selected

            onClickMethod(v);

            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else

        if (v.getId() == R.id.assist_update_btn) {

            // Update button for ICS and up is selected
            // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {
            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
            // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS and
            // up is selected
            // Create ConfigActivity Intent
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            // Invoke ConfigActivity Intent to start the assisted update
            startActivity(i);
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));

        } else if (v == mReadAgainButton) {
            // go back to 1st set of instructions if read again is selected
            mInstructionNumber = 0;
            setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
            String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_cta2);
            CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdate);
            TextView assistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            assistText.setText(styledText);
            mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void onClickMethod(View v) {
        mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.drawable.btn_update_active_hdpi);

    }

    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        UpdateActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });
        mConfirmAlert = builder.create();
        mConfirmAlert.show();
    }

    // AsyncTask to call web service
    class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, InputStream> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                // saving the response in InputStream
                stream = getQueryResults("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31771876/GetPhoneSettings-ST-rsp-eng.xml");
                // stream = new BufferedInputStream(https.getInputStream());
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) { // Print the content
                    // on the console
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                    in.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // The code below plays a Simple Promo animation

            for (int incr = 0; incr < 2; incr++) {
                // Sleep for 1/2 second
                // Invoke UI to change updating text to show sequential dot
                // loading animation
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full);

                // Sleep for 1/2 second
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
            }
            return stream;
        }

        /*
         * Sends a query to server and gets back the parsed results in a bundle
         * urlQueryString - URL for calling the webservice
         */
        protected synchronized InputStream getQueryResults(String urlQueryString)
                throws IOException, SAXException, SSLException,
                SocketTimeoutException, Exception {

            HttpsURLConnection https = null;
            String uri = urlQueryString;

            URL urlo = new URL(uri);

            try {
                https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlo.openConnection();
                https.setConnectTimeout(20000); // 20 second timeout
                https.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                if ("gzip".equals(https.getContentEncoding())) {
                    stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
                } else
                    stream = https.getInputStream();

            } catch (SSLException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

            }

            return stream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

            // Call function to update image view

            setProgressImgView(progress[0], progress[1], progress[2],
                    progress[3], progress[4]);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream stream) {
            super.onPostExecute(stream);
            // This method is called to parse the response and save the
            // ArrayLists
            success();
            assistUpdate();

        }

    }

    private void assistUpdate() {
        // Displaying final layout after pre-ICS automatic settings update
        setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
        assist_update_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
        assist_update_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void setProgressImgView(Integer imageViewId1, Integer imageViewId2,
            Integer imageViewId3, Integer imageViewId4, Integer imageViewId5) {
        // update image view with the updating dots
        // Reset view layout in case orientation while updating
        setContentView(R.layout.updating);

        mProgressImageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);
        mProgressImageview1.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId1);
        mProgressImageview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);
        mProgressImageview2.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId2);
        mProgressImageview3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty3);
        mProgressImageview3.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId3);
        mProgressImageview4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty4);
        mProgressImageview4.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId4);
        mProgressImageview5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty5);
        mProgressImageview5.setBackgroundResource(imageViewId5);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

        if (mErrorAlert != null)
            mErrorAlert.dismiss();
    }

    private void endUpdate(View v) {
        finish();

    }

    public void success() {

        // to parse the response
        try {
            handler.getQueryResponse(stream);

        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // to set method to save the ArryaLists from the parser
        setArrayList();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }

    // method to save the ArrayLists from parser
    public static void setArrayList() {
        nameArr = handler.getnameArr();
        ApnArr = handler.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = handler.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        portArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        count = handler.getCount();
        // System.out.println("testing123");

        for (int i = 0; i < nameArr.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(nameArr.get(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ApnArr.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(ApnArr.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to get xml data from the R class of your library, you need to explicitly call `com.project.test.networktasklibrary.R` instead of just `R`, to distinguish it from the R class in your app's own package.

By default, `R` is going to refer to the R in the current package. If you don't plan to use the app's R class in the current class, you could alternatively import `com.project.test.networktasklibrary.R` at the top of this class and then just refer to it as `R`.

Comment: Thanks! When I attempt to import com.project.test.networktasklibrary.R; I'm getting an error stating the import cannot be resolved

Comment: Any suggestions as to why that might be happening?

Comment: Look for the R class in the gen directory in your library project. What package name does it have in the file? That's the one you need. Don't have Eclipse in front of me to check what the specific package name is for the generated files, so maybe I assumed wrong.